# mosquito MQTT message handler getting messages with some delay not real time

Tags: mqtt, message

Following is the MQTT configuration to listening event.
For high message load around 100 message per second I noticed messages not received realtime on handler.

```
public class VehicleEventMqttConfig {

    @Value("${mqtt.auto-startup.vehicleEvent:false}")
    private boolean autoStartup;

    @Value("${mqtt.completion-timeout.vehicleEvent:30000}")
    private int completionTimeout;

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel vehicleMqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inboundVehicleEvent(
        final MqttPahoClientFactory mqttPahoClientFactory,
        final MqttAdapters adapters,
        @Value("${mqtt.topic.vehicleEvent}") final String topic) {
        log.info("Register vehicleEvent mqtt");
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(topic)) {
            log.warn("vehicleEvent disabled!");
            return null;
        }
        final MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
            new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                getClientIdWithHost("inboundVehicleEvent"), mqttPahoClientFactory, topic);
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(completionTimeout);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(vehicleMqttInputChannel());
        adapter.setAutoStartup(autoStartup);
        adapter.setQos(1);
        adapters.add(adapter);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "vehicleMqttInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler vehicleEventHandler() {
        return new VehicleEventMessageHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: The MQTT protocol makes no guarantee of "realtime" delivery. There are a number of things that can cause delays; a good starting point would be to check your broker configuration (e.g. with Mosquitto the `max_inflight_messages` setting limits the number of messages transmitted simultaneously and defaults to 20).

Comment: What makes you think this is a problem with the code in subscribing client and not say the broker or maybe a bandwidth constraint? There isn't enough information here to really help

Comment: after updating max_inflight_messages  of broker config to higher value solved my problem.